# How to persist an entity which contains properties displayed in a form as select list

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, php-5.5

I'm a newby on symfony.
I'm working on a project using symfony 2.7.6.
I have an object/entity "Trajet" which contains 2 properties(which are source of my headaches!!).
Theses 2 properties are VilleDepart and VilleArrivee (integers linked to my database with doctrine (ORM annotation in the object class))
In my form i want them to be displayed as a dropdown list. So i used a formbuilder with the two entity field type.

But when i try to persist the "Trajet" object in the controller (using entity manager), i get this an sql error (because it consider the two properties VilleDepart and VilleArrivee as entity instead of integer)...
I clearly see where the problem is... the sql query is

```
INSERT INTO trajet (traj_villedepart , traj_villearrivee) VALUES ({}, {})
```

Instead of

```
INSERT INTO trajet (traj_villedepart , traj_villearrivee) VALUES (1, 2)
```

For example

Here his my class trajet

```
 class Trajet {

    /** 
    * @ORM\Id @ORM\Column(name="idtrajet", type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue
    */
    private $ID;
/** 
    * @ORM\Column(name="traj_idvilledepart", type="integer")  
    */
    private $VilleDepart;

    /** 
    * @ORM\Column(name="traj_idvillearrivee", type="integer")   
    */
    private $VilleArrivee;

//Getters and setters....
}
```

Here is my abstract type of Trajet for the form

```
    class TrajetType extends AbstractType
{   
    private $manager;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('DescriptionVoiture', 'textarea')
            ->add('VilleDepart', 'entity', array(
                'class'    => 'MyBundle:Ville',
                'property' => 'Nom',
                'em'       => 'pgsql',
                'query_builder' => function(VilleRepository $er){
                    return $er->getVillesOrderByOrdre();
                },
              ))
            ->add('VilleArrivee', 'entity', array(
                'class'    => 'MyBundle:Ville',
                'property' => 'Nom',
                'em'       => 'pgsql',
                'query_builder' => function(VilleRepository $er){
                    return $er->getVillesOrderByOrdre();
                },
              )) 
}
public function getName()
    {
        return 'trajet';
    }  
}
```

And finally my controller

```
class TrajetController extends Controller {

    public function AddEditTrajetAction($idTrajet = null) {
        $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('pgsql');
        $trajet = new Trajet();
       //Initialize the object $trajet with the get ID....
        $form = $this->createForm(new TrajetType($manager), $trajet);
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            $form->handleRequest($request);
            if ($form->isValid()) {

                $manager->persist($trajet);
                $manager->flush();
               //Return to the view...
            }


          }
    }
}
```

Please help! I become crazy!! thanks

Comment: A part of code would be appreciable.

Comment: Could you post the code from your entity class where you define "Trajet"? There probably are several ways one could solve your problem, depending on how your class looks like. I guess your properties VilleDepart and VilleArrivee are entities themselves, correct?

Comment: It sort of sounds like you might need a data transformer to convert between integers and entities. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html But like the previous commentators, it's not clear to me exactly what is happening.

Comment: Sorry.Effectively,i didn't put the code.Here it is.
`class Trajet {
//int    
private $ID;
//int
private $VilleDepart;
//int
private $VilleArrivee;
//Rest of code
`In the Controller

`class TrajetController extends Controller{
public function ProposerTrajetAction(Request $request)
{
$trajet= new Trajet();
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->createBuilder('form',$trajet)
->add('VilleDepart','entity',array(
'class'=>'mybundle:Ville',
'property'=>'Nom',
'em'=>'pgsql',
))
->add('VilleArrivee', 'entity',..)
....
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('pgsql');
$em->persist($trajet);
$em->flush();
}

Comment: Please edit the question add the code!Add the error as well!

Comment: Hello @Fuzzzzel.
I finaly found the solution. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hello @Cerad. I finaly found the solution. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution: Make an unidirectional oneToone relationship between Trajet and Ville I Modified the class Trajet like that

```
class Trajet {        

   /**
    *@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="xxx\Entity\Ville")
    *@ORM\JoinColumn(name="traj_idvilledepart", ReferencedColumnName="idville", nullable=false)
    */
    private $VilleDepart;

    //The same for VilleArrivee...

//Getters and setters....
}
```

And then in the controlleur

```
$manager->persist($trajet);
$manager->flush();
```

Will work easily